# How do I use absolute file paths within a read

Tags: karate

I have resources that I don't want them to be included in the project. I want to be able to store them at a shared location and use them from there. Is there any way to do this in karate? Can I specify absolute paths within read function?

None of the below methods work:

```
* def result = read('C:/Utils/backup.json')
```

> Error: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   D:\Automation\project\myproject\src\test\java\api\component\mycomp\Utils\backup.json
>   (The system cannot find the path specified)

```
* def result = read('classpath:C:/Utils/backup.json')
```

> Caused by: com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateFileNotFoundException:
>   file not found: C:/Utils_TP/backup.json, classpath: true

Answer (score 0):

Karate will never support this, because this is very very bad practice.

My suggestion is you write a custom Java function to read the file from the path you provide and use it.  Refer to the doc on `calling Java` or `Java Interop`.

Comment: Thanks! The reason for asking this is that I have large files (for example backups of data) that I want to include in another request as multipart file. How can I then make such an upload?

Comment: easiest is copy these files under `src/test/java` and use `classpath:`, what's the problem ?

Comment: @DDana actually Karate 0.7.0 will support this, as of now there is a 0.7.0.RC1 you can try